# Fabric: make mentions and quote tweet on Fabric in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm using Fabric to use Twitter's Services, I'd like to make a mention and quote tweet with Fabric but I haven't find something. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to mention using Fabric:

```
let composer = TWTRComposer()

    composer.setText("@\(username)")

    composer.showFromViewController(self) { result in

        if (result == TWTRComposerResult.Cancelled) {
            println("Tweet composition cancelled")
        }
        else {
            println("Sending tweet!")
        }
    }
```